# sidekiq ignoring pool size setting

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, sidekiq

No matter what I try, I can't seem to get Sidekiq to honour my max pool size settings. I've tried:

- setting pool in my database:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: database
  username: username
  password: password
  host: host
  reconnect: true
  pool: 10
```

- hard-coding it in my sidekiq initializer (both with and without the disconnect! and both inside and outside the configure server block):

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  ActiveRecord::Base.configurations['production']['pool'] = 50
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

- setting it using a DATABASE_URL env var (and yes, I made sure DATABASE_URL was set, using https://github.com/glenngillen/rails-database-url):

```
database_url = ENV['DATABASE_URL']
if(database_url)
  ENV['DATABASE_URL'] = "#{database_url}?pool=25"
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

I have no idea why none of these have worked. Any ideas?

In case it's relevant:

- rails 3.2.12
- sidekiq 2.6.4

Comment: If possible could you raise this on Github repo? (https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues). I am having the issue but you tried more ways so you know more about this issue.

Comment: Do you use Capistrano? In your backlog trace, do you see the reference to old releases? This happens to me and I think it may be related.

Comment: How are you checking Sidekiq max pool limit? Is that DATABASE_URL block code inside a Sidekiq.configure_server do |config| block? Did you try to restart? Are you using Heroku?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you're not manually establishing connections in any of the workers, or in any of the code the workers execute. This will increase the number of connections that each worker checks out from the pool (unnecessarily) and will cause your universe to collapse.

Comment: So, this wasn't my exact issue, but it lead me to the solution, so I've accepted your answer :) Our app has models that connect to a different database, so we manually connected to the DB in those models. It was those connections that did not have the correct pool settings, which explains why no matter how many different ways I manually configured it, it seemed to ignore the setting: it just wasn't seeing it.